# Are there Android design conventions for an empty screen?

Tags: android, user-expectation, mobile-application

I am designing an application with 3 screens, each on their own tab. Screens 2 and 3 require data to be inputted on Screen 1 before they work. The app will open at Screen 1.

Are there any conventions for informing the user, if they arrive at Screen 2 or 3, that they must select an option on Screen 1 before Screen 2 and 3 work? I can think of numerous solutions, but wonder if there are conventions?

Comment: Can you upload a mockup to have a better understanding of the application?